# MS Word JavaScript API - event handler for Content Controls

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-contentcontrol, word-web-addins

Is there a way to fire a function when clicking on a contentControl in Office-js?

I am writing an add-on for MS Word, and I have inserted content controls, that will be associated with a list in my add-in. I need to fire a function when clicking on the content control, so I can scroll to the item in the list and highlight it.

I have found the "Document.ContentControlOnEnter event (Word)" which seems to be what I am looking for, but I cannot understand how to attach an event-listener that listens to this event.

I am writing the plugin in typescript react.

Comment: The Document.ContentControlOnEnter event is part of the VBA APIs, not the Office-js APIs, so it is unclear whether you are making a VBA add-in or a web add-in. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you! No I intend to write an Office-js API add-in. I was just confused in the documentation. Do you know of any way at all that I can run a function when a user enters or clicks a content control?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview According to this page there are three events: ```onDataChanged```, ```onDeleted``` and ```onSelectionChanged```. Would you be able to use these events to fire your function?

Comment: Yes, I have also seen that. Two issues, first they are listed as preview and should not be used in production, second I cannot figure out how to listen to those events. I tried listening to thos events in this event handler, but it was not allowed: Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, handler);

Answer (score 1):

Word web add-ins don't provide anything for that.

UPD: You may be interested in the [onSelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#word-word-contentcontrol-onselectionchanged-member) event which is fired when selection within the content control is changed. Note, this event is provided as in preview and not availble in a production environment.

Comment: I have seen other add-ins that has this functionality. If I click on a content control the add-in is updated to show the information of the clicked content control. How do others do it if it does not exist? Is this possible if I build my add-in through some other technology?

Comment: You may be interested in the [onSelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#word-word-contentcontrol-onselectionchanged-member) event.